# Obtaining a solution space to an inverse kinematics problem (mapping a higher dimensional space onto a lower one)

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, dimensional-analysis

I have a 15 dimensional space (corresponding to 15 joints of a robot, 5 joints for each of two legs, and another 5 joints for the right arm). I'll call this space A. Bear in mind that each of the 15 values in space A is bounded (i.e. there's a minimum possible, and a maximum possible value corresponding to the joint limits). Now, space A maps onto a 9 dimensional space, called space B. This dimensional space contains:

- 6 dimensions for the position and orientation of the robot's right hand (3 cartesian coordinates + 3 Euler angle rotations)
- 3 dimensions corresponding to the Cartesian coordinates of the left foot.

Assume that I already have the 9 equations that map the 15 joint values of space A onto each of the 9 dimensions of space B (i.e. I already have a forward kinematic solver). As some of you may have guessed, what I want to do is go the other way i.e. provided that I know the desired values for the 9 dimensions of space B, I want to obtain a solution for space A.

Now being an engineer my theoretical mathematics isn't very strong, but I do know that my solution will actually be a 6 dimensional space(?) What I want is an expression for this 6 dimensional space that also respects the joint limits I mentioned earlier. I know this isn't something that has a straightforward answer, so what I'm looking for is a clear roadmap along with specific methods and theories which I can read up on so I can get the job done without delving too deep into irrelevant stuff.

**Additional Info:** The position/orientations I'm talking about are all relative to the right foot, so essentially the right foot is assumed stationary. Also, all 15 joints are revolute joints i.e. they apply a rotation along any one of the x, y or z axes. Their 'value' is basically the angle (in radians) by which they are rotated.

Comment: Why don't you have 3 more dimensions for the coordinates for the right foot? This is not idle curiousity. What sort of answers can be given depend on the reason you are not including it.

Comment: The reason is that my right foot is the reference frame. The position/orientation of the right arm and left foot are relative to the right foot frame, so essentially the right foot is stationary in this problem. 
P.S. Added this along with some other pieces of info to the question.